# Kodak's KCMS replaced with Little-CMS (LCMS) in openJDK - Performance drop in PDF conversion (slow)

Tags: java, image-processing, pdf-generation, pdfbox, pdf-conversion

The Kodak color management system (KCMS) has been replaced in openJDK with [LittleCMS](https://www.littlecms.com/) (LCMS) starting from Java 10. In Java8 and 9 it was still available but not the default anymore. It could be activated with:

```
// force KCMS
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm","sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");
```

There were understandable reasons for that: LCMS is an Open Source project, it supports modern ICC profiles, it is maintained (vs. [KCMS open bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8053947)) and so on. There is a **tradeoff** however: the ColorConversionOp (CConv) is **much slower** than the original KCMS. The reason is that KCMS is (4x) multi-threaded but LCMS is not. There is a [lengthy thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/2d-dev/2018-October/009520.html) with all the details...

While everyday users are probably not impacted by this too much, there is one application area which is greatly impacted. I searched for problems with the KCMS->LCMS switch and found the following:

- PDFBox renders much slower ([bug at openJDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211178) or here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100210))
- Quoppa PDF library [error](https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/wrong-colors-in-images-with-java-8/)
- JPEDAL PDF library ([bug at openJDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041125) or their [blog](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/color-performance-change-newer-java-releases/))
- ...

Quote from jpedal:

> Over the last month, we noticed a major slowdown in our regression
> tests. A test cycle which used to take 30 minutes was taking 82 minutes.

For everybody who wants to try out, there is an [example project](https://github.com/kalaspuffar/ColorConvTest) to test for yourself.

It becomes clear that especially one area is really suffering from this: **Java PDF processing**.

**But why am I writing this?**

Would it be possible to create a standalone KCMS library? Which could be loaded for projects which need it? Comparable with the [JPG2K lib](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000) which was excluded from [JAI](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core) but made available as a separate lib.

I searched online (and found some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1327/index.html) however) didn't find the source code for it.
Is the code or a lib somewhere available? Would that even be possible?

Comment: I felt that this is no longer a problem after jdk8-192. But yeah, Oracle should invest much more development power to fix their bugs and optimize their product instead of implementing obscure features.

Comment: What happened in 8u192? KCMS is still part of this version and also used by pdfbox due to the mentioned "hardwiring". Did you make a test with JDK11 where KCMS is no longer available? My experience is that its remarkably slower (of course depending on the document).

Comment: I noticed that LCMS was no longer slow. We removed the log message recommending KCMS, except when java8 < 192 is used. JDK11 is also better. (This is a general impression, I didn't retry the specific test you link to)

Comment: KCMS was (AFAIK) licensed by Sun/Oracle from Kodak. It's proprietary and not open source, so even if you found the source code online, I don't think it could be used. I think our best bet is to invest time and money in supporting OpenJDK and LCMS to make things faster.

Comment: I ran my rendering tests (about 1000 files), and it took 8 min with the latest amazon corretto jdk8 and 6 min with the latest amazon corretto jdk11.

Comment: And when running with the latest jdk8 you did probably use LCMS (since it is > 192). Can you try to enforce KCMS and run it again?

Comment: I get an error message "KCMS not available". Seems they removed it?!

Comment: Mhm interesting. I searched a bit and it seems indeed that it was removed: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-dev/2018-July/022782.html